# How to calculate website speed in Android

Tags: android, browser, web

How can I calculate the website speed in Android, in other words how soon it will open up in browser. I also wish to calculate all the statistics of that particular page e.g. total bytes or connection time etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

1. save the current timestamp,
2. make a http request,
3. get the http response,
4. and get the timestamp as soon as your response arrives and calculate
   the difference in time.

Or, you could

1. Create a WebView
2. Set a  WebViewClient
3. Use its callbacks -
   onPageLoaded, onPageFinished,
   onPageStarted, etc ...

Check here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

Answer (score 1):

The logic may not be very accurate, but this is what I think:

- You open an `HttpConnection` to that website.
- Take the current time-stamp somewhere in any variable
- From that `HttpConnection`, start reading the contents of the website, and store it all into a string variable
- Again take current time-stamp somewhere

Now, Analysis:

- The difference between both the time-stamps is the time that it takes to open that website based on the current speed.
- The size of the String variable you downloaded the whole content is the size of the home-page of that website
- `size/time taken` is your current internet speed

This might not work accurately in some situations, like when the URLs are being redirected, i guess.

Its still what I think, maybe better options are available.

Hope it helps.